# How can I use Flexslider with Wordpress using Ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, flexslider

I am using flexslider to showcase some of my portfolio work. I want to have each portfolio piece as a custom post type in Wordpress and to only load the first portfolio piece into flexslider on page load. I then want to use Ajax to load the next/ previous portfolio piece if user clicks on the next/previous button. How could I do this Ajax in Wordpress?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

A little dirty, but it works :)

Remember to set the directionNav to true.

```
<script>
    $(function(){
            $('.flexslider').flexslider({
                directionNav: true,
                slideshow: false, 
                controlsContainer: ".flex-container"
            });
            $('.flex-direction-nav').hide();

            $("#next-link").click(function() {
                $(".next", ".flex-direction-nav").trigger("click");;
            });
            $("#prev-link").click(function() {
                $(".prev", ".flex-direction-nav").trigger("click");;
            });

});
</script>
<a href="#" id="prev-link">Previous</a>
<a href="#" id="next-link">Next</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for exactly the same thing, but as of now, Flexslider v1.8 has no way of doing this ([comment from the developer](https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/issues/99#issuecomment-5249635)).

However, Flexslider 2 will have a slider.addSlide() method that will allow for adding slides ([details here](https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/tree/FlexSlider2#updates)).